# How to use `scrot` to take screenshots of a particular window by name?

Tags: scripts, scrot-command

If I would like to select a window for `scrot` this could be easily done with:

```
scrot -s name.jpg
```

But if I want to ask `scrot` to keep taking screenshots from a selected window, then I don't know how to do this. The following is what I tried:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
   scrot -s "$(date)".jpg
   sleep 5
done
```

The problem with the above is: after every 5 seconds I have to tell `scrot` which window by clicking it.

If only I could pass the window by clicking it only once the first time it would be perfect.

If not, could I tell `scrot` which window by telling it the window name?

**Edit:** I also want it to work even when the window is minimised. How to do this?

Comment: Sorry, what reddit?

Answer (score 8):

From `man scrot`:

```
       -u, --focused
            Use the currently focused window.
```

So you could just change your script like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
   scrot -u "$(date)".jpg
   sleep 5
done
```

However this will start taking screenshots as soon as the script is started, which is probably undesired; this would be a bit more user-friendly, as it will start taking screenshots only after the user has manually selected a window:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
scrot -s "$(date)".jpg
while true
do
   sleep 5
   scrot -u "$(date)".jpg
done
```

Comment: Oh! A feature a want is that it should record a screen even when it is minimised. Is that possible?

Comment: @Inspired_Blue No. There's no relevant option in the `man` page, so no, at least not with `scrot`. Wouldn't know which alternative to suggest though.